# Unclear Documentation of the git reset <path> command

Tags: git, git-reset

Taken from the [docs: `git reset <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset-emgitresetem-qlttree-ishgt--ltpathsgt82308203):

> After running git reset  to update the index entry, you can use git-checkout[1] to check the contents out of the index to the working tree. Alternatively, using git-checkout[1] and specifying a commit, you can copy the contents of a path out of a commit to the index and to the working tree in one go.

**Q** Can someone provided an example for what is meant with the cited paragrah ?

---

**Note** This questions specifically asks for the cited paragraph of the  `git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…​` variant. I am aware of what `git reset <path>` does but can not make any sense of the snippet above

Answer (score 1):

- **An example for the first part of the cited paragrah**:

  > After running git reset to update the index entry, you can use git-checkout[1] to check the contents out of the index to the working tree.

Starting from `git reset` for a better context. Say we've changed *hello.c* in working tree, and added it to index.

```
$ git status
On branch feature02
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   hello.c
```

Now, *run git reset to update the index entry* back to the status as before we added it into index.

```
$ git reset -- hello.c
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       hello.c

$ git status
On branch feature02
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   hello.c

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Until now, the working tree still contains our last changes, while the index is updated to match *HEAD*. OK, let's *use git-checkout[1] to check the contents out of the index to the working tree*. Please be cautious, as this command **loses the changes** to *hello.c* in working tree.

```
$ git checkout -- hello.c

$ git status
On branch feature02
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Now, both the index and the working tree are updated to match *HEAD*. So it says `working tree clean`.

- **An example for the second part of the cited paragrah**:

  > Alternatively, using git-checkout[1] and specifying a commit, you can copy the contents of a path out of a commit to the index and to the working tree in one go.

Get back to the original status when we start:

```
$ git status
On branch feature02
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   hello.c
```

*Use git-checkout[1] and specify a commit*.

```
$ git checkout HEAD hello.c

$ git status
On branch feature02
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Here we are, both the index and the working tree are updated to match *HEAD*. Which is why we call it *in one go*.

---

Some trick here is the 2 uses of `git checkout`:

```
git checkout -- hello.c
```

&

```
git checkout HEAD hello.c
```

The first one without a named commit is to copy contents from index (to working tree), while the latter one is from commit history (to both index and working tree).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the first three chapters of Pro Git, which will give you a better understanding of the Git model, which is really key to understanding this.

The tl;dr is that this version of `reset` updates only the index (i.e. cache, staging area) without touching the working tree (the files visible to you) or `HEAD`, and that if you do that, you can use `checkout` to bring your working tree in line with the index (or just use `checkout` to do both operations - grab specific versions of files and update both your index and working tree with them - in one go).

---

Let's use the Git repository as an example. First, I'm going to identify a specific commit and a specific change to use as an example:

```
$ git show --stat HEAD
commit e7e07d5a4fcc2a203d9873968ad3e6bd4d7419d7
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 24 10:49:58 2017 -0800

    Git 2.12

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

 Documentation/RelNotes/2.12.0.txt | 6 ++++++
 Documentation/git.txt             | 5 +++++
 GIT-VERSION-GEN                   | 2 +-
 3 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git show HEAD -- Documentation/git.txt
commit e7e07d5a4fcc2a203d9873968ad3e6bd4d7419d7
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 24 10:49:58 2017 -0800

    Git 2.12

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

diff --git a/Documentation/git.txt b/Documentation/git.txt
index 4f208fab9..aa895da4a 100644
--- a/Documentation/git.txt
+++ b/Documentation/git.txt
@@ -44,6 +44,11 @@ unreleased) version of Git, that is available from the 'master'
 branch of the `git.git` repository.
 Documentation for older releases are available here:

+* link:v2.12.0/git.html[documentation for release 2.12.0]
+
+* release notes for
+  link:RelNotes/2.12.0.txt[2.12].
+
 * link:v2.11.1/git.html[documentation for release 2.11.1]

 * release notes for
```

Now let's use the form that you're talking about, `git reset [tree-ish] [--] [paths]`:

```
$ git reset HEAD^ -- Documentation/git.txt
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       Documentation/git.txt

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   Documentation/git.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Documentation/git.txt
```

We can examine what the difference between the state of the index and `HEAD` as follows:

```
$ git diff --staged
diff --git a/Documentation/git.txt b/Documentation/git.txt
index aa895da4a..4f208fab9 100644
--- a/Documentation/git.txt
+++ b/Documentation/git.txt
@@ -44,11 +44,6 @@ unreleased) version of Git, that is available from the 'master'
 branch of the `git.git` repository.
 Documentation for older releases are available here:

-* link:v2.12.0/git.html[documentation for release 2.12.0]
-
-* release notes for
-  link:RelNotes/2.12.0.txt[2.12].
-
 * link:v2.11.1/git.html[documentation for release 2.11.1]

 * release notes for
```

Notice that this is the exact opposite of the `HEAD` commit: the version of `Documentation/git.txt` in our index matches the version recorded in `HEAD^`. We can also compare our working tree to `HEAD`:

```
$ git diff HEAD
# no output, because there's no difference
```

and we can also compare our working tree to the index:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/Documentation/git.txt b/Documentation/git.txt
index 4f208fab9..aa895da4a 100644
--- a/Documentation/git.txt
+++ b/Documentation/git.txt
@@ -44,6 +44,11 @@ unreleased) version of Git, that is available from the 'master'
 branch of the `git.git` repository.
 Documentation for older releases are available here:

+* link:v2.12.0/git.html[documentation for release 2.12.0]
+
+* release notes for
+  link:RelNotes/2.12.0.txt[2.12].
+
 * link:v2.11.1/git.html[documentation for release 2.11.1]

 * release notes for
```

which happens to mimick the commit in `HEAD` because our index corresponds to `HEAD^` but our working tree still lines up with `HEAD`! (This part is particularly confusing, but once you have an idea of how it all works it'll make more sense.) If we `checkout` (thus copying the version in the index to the working tree), this will no longer be the case:

```
$ git checkout -- Documentation/git.txt

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   Documentation/git.txt
```

we see that our working tree now matches up with the index, and in fact the diff between `HEAD` and the working tree lines up with the previous diff between `HEAD` and the index:

```
$ git diff HEAD
diff --git a/Documentation/git.txt b/Documentation/git.txt
index aa895da4a..4f208fab9 100644
--- a/Documentation/git.txt
+++ b/Documentation/git.txt
@@ -44,11 +44,6 @@ unreleased) version of Git, that is available from the 'master'
 branch of the `git.git` repository.
 Documentation for older releases are available here:

-* link:v2.12.0/git.html[documentation for release 2.12.0]
-
-* release notes for
-  link:RelNotes/2.12.0.txt[2.12].
-
 * link:v2.11.1/git.html[documentation for release 2.11.1]

 * release notes for
```

This combination (`git reset HEAD^ -- Documentation/git.txt && git checkout -- Documentation/git.txt`) is equivalent to `git checkout HEAD^ -- Documentation/git.txt`.